# performance problems on SQLserver subqueries

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am triyin to do an sql query to determinate what articles meet a certain conditions(not sold in 4 month, in 12 month sol 2 or less units and there is stock) i try with this query

```
select distinct(lineas.codart), articulos.codpro
from lineas
inner join articulos on lineas.codart=articulos.codart
INNER JOIN stock ON stock.codart=lineas.codart
where lineas.codart NOT IN(
    SELECT LINEAS.CODART
    FROM LINEAS
    WHERE DATEDIFF("d",lineas.fecalb,getdate())<120
) or ( lineas.codart in(
        select distinct(codart)
        from lineas
        where DATEDIFF("d",lineas.fecalb,getdate())<365 and DATEDIFF("d",lineas.fecalb,getdate())>120 and lineas.unidad<=2 )
) AND stock.stoexi>0;
```

but this not give me the expected results, and stay 50 minutes doing the query.

the líneas table have 650.000 rows, i dont think is normal.

excuse my english, and thanks for your help

Comment: I'm guessing I indented that correctly. You should take some time to format it properly yourself-  not everyone has a monitor 10 miles wide. And if that is done properly, then you're mixing `or` and `and` clauses without the brackets necessary to enforce operator ordering, which MAY be a source of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
select distinct(lineas.codart), articulos.codpro 
from lineas o
inner join articulos on lineas.codart=articulos.codart 
INNER JOIN stock ON stock.codart=lineas.codart 
where  NOT exists (
                    SELECT top 1 1 
                    FROM LINEAS i 
                    WHERE (
                                (DATEDIFF("d",i.fecalb,getdate())120 and i.unidad0)
                                )   
                                and o.codart = i.codart
                            )   
                 )
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT that´s more or less that i need